# Hierarchical foreign key selector in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Let's say I have some models like this:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    name = models.TextField()

class Person(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    name = models.TextField()
```

In the Django admin page, if I add/edit a `Person` instance, it will give me a drop-down of `City` instances to select from, like this:

[image]

However, the number of cities in the world is very large. So, what I would like to do is have a hierarchical country -> city selector, like this:

[image]

Is this possible in Django?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not out of the box.

You'll have to make and ajax request after the user selects the country to fetch the cities related to that country and so on.

You will need a view on django that returns the cities given a country in a format that makes it easy to parse on javascript or build the html and send it over the wire if you don't care about reusing that endpoint (maybe you can check django's `JsonResponse`)

After that, you'll need to use javascript (it might be a good idea to use something like jquery) to hit that view sending the country id and fetch the corresponding cities.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where do I put the AJAX code, though? I assume I need to override some Django admin functionality but I don't know where to start.

Comment: you can try using something like this https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects and specifying a custom form for the adminmodel.

Answer (score 0):

ya it is possible to do if you create a page of your own, load one country and its states by default, then if you select a country do a ajax call to repopulate the cities, i will suggest angular js for the same.

Comment: I am trying to do this in the Django admin console though, not on my own page.

Comment: if that's what you want you definitely need to override the django admin template

Comment: Which template do you mean? It seems there are a few of them you can override: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model